# Multiple Broadcast Receivers with identical Intent Filters

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

How does Android handle the case where you have two `BroadcastReceiver`s with identical `intent-filter`s defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Does it invoke both `BroadcastReceiver`s? Or, does it invoke the first one it comes across?

Comment: Easy and quick enough to find out by putting a quick example together ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Both of your broadcast receivers will receive a broadcast.

In case, if a broadcast isn't ordered (`sendBroadcast` vs `sendOrderedBroadcast`), order in which they will be called is generally undefined.